# Scheme return a list with first half of its elements

Tags: scheme

Write a procedure (first-half lst) that returns a list with the first half of its elements. If the length of the given list is odd, the returned list should have (length - 1) / 2 elements.

I am given these program as a example and as I am new to Scheme I need your help in solving this problem.

```
(define list-head 
   (lambda (lst k)
      (if (= k 0)
         '()
          (cons (car lst)(list-head (cdr lst)(- k 1)))))))

(list-head '(0 1 2 3 4) 3)   
; list the first 3 element in the list (list 0 1 2)
```

Also the expected output for the program I want is :

```
(first-half '(43 23 14 5 9 57 0 125))
(43 23 14 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty simple to implement in terms of existing procedures, check your interpreter's documentation for the availability of the [`take`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._take%29%29) procedure:

```
(define (first-half lst)
  (take lst (quotient (length lst) 2)))
```

Apart from that, the code provided in the question is basically reinventing `take`, and it looks correct. The only detail left to implement would be, how to obtain the half of the lists' length? same as above, just use the [`quotient`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._quotient%29%29) procedure:

```
(define (first-half lst)
  (list-head lst (quotient (length lst) 2)))
```

Comment: Floor, not ceiling. :-) But you could just use `quotient`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are learning about recursion?  One recursive approach is to walk the list with a 'slow' and 'fast' pointer; when the fast pointer reaches the end you are done; use the slow pointer to grow the result.  Like this:

```
(define (half list)
  (let halving ((rslt '()) (slow list) (fast list))
    (if (or (null? fast) (null? (cdr fast)))
        (reverse rslt)
        (halving (cons (car slow) rslt)
                 (cdr slow)
                 (cdr (cdr fast))))))
```

Comment: +Chris J-Y, thanks for the spelling edit.  +Chris T, I like 'list', not 'lst'

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach it is to have a function that divides the list at a specific index, and then a wrapper to calculate floor(length/2):

```
(define (cleave_at n a)
  (cond
   ((null? a) '())
   ((zero? n) (list '() a))
   (#t 
    ((lambda (x)
      (cons (cons (car a) (car x)) (cdr x)))
     (cleave_at (- n 1) (cdr a))))))

(define (first-half a)
  (car (cleave_at (floor (/ (length a) 2)) a)))
```